# cache username and password in webview (iphone)

Tags: iphone, caching, uiwebview

I want to introduce a cache policy in my app.

Basically I have made a web view in which I have the functionality that when I open up that I'll have to login ,

I want to store that data in the cache now ..

like Facebook app .. when I delete that app from the background and open it again .. i dont have to add all the detail again.

how to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try NSUserDefaults

```
NSString *value = @"MyUsername@domain";
NSUserDefaults *userPreferences = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userPreferences setObject:value forKey:@"username"];
```

To fetch from UserDefaults -

```
NSString *_value= [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"username"];
```

Comment: Do you mean terminate the app while in background? yes in that case the data will persist

Comment: but manali .. how will I fetch this ?? I am only opening a link in a webview .. like gmail.com .. in which i want to store all the user name and data so that i dont have to login again unless i am sign out ,,,

Comment: UIWebView doesn’t allow us to access its content directly, you could use javascript to fetch the details and then populate respective fields the next time. http://www.icab.de/blog/2010/01/12/search-and-highlight-text-in-uiwebview/ is a good tutorial, it searches the page for instances of a string, you could easily modify it for your purpose.

Comment: Sure, u r welcome, if it has helped u do consider accepting the answer :)

Comment: finally I implemented this only ... kudos to you .. thanks ..:D